# blur時にdivを挿入すると何をクリックしているかが分からない

Tags: javascript, html

input.blur時に独自のエラーボックスを出すことを想定したプログラムで
focus状態で「tab button」をclickしようとした場合tabもlayerもクリックされていないようですが一体何がクリックされているのでしょうか？

```
<div id="tab" onclick="console.log('tab Click')">tab button</div>
<input type="text" onBlur="document.body.appendChild(layer)" /><br />

<style type="text/css">
    .layer{background-color:#F00;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;opacity:0.5;}
 </style>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var layer = document.createElement("div");
    layer.className = "layer";
    document.body.onclick = function(event){console.log(event)};
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tab button` と `layer` に `onmousedown` と `onmouseup` を入れて動作させると、

1. `tab button` の `onmousedown` が発火する。
2. `input` の `onblur` が発火する。
3. `layer` が追加される。
4. `layer` の `onmouseup` が発火する。

と動いているのがわかると思います。

なので、

- `tab button` は、 `onmouseup` が動いてないので `onclick` が発火しない。
- `layer` は、 `onmousedown` が動いてないので `onclick` が発火しない。

といったところだと思います。

Answer (score 1):

挿入された`div`要素(ここでいう`layer`)がクリックされます。

```
document.body.onclick = function(event){console.log(event)};
```

ではなく

```
layer.onclick = function(event){console.log(event)};
```

がやりたいことではないですか？

追記：
もしかしてイベントバブリングの話ですか？
要素に対してクリックイベントのバブリングを`stopPropagation()`等でキャンセルしない場合、`body`までイベントが伝搬します。
[イベントバブリング](http://uhyohyo.net/javascript/3_3.html)
[JavaScriptのイベント伝播について覚書](http://linuxserver.jp/%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%9F%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0/javascript/%E3%82%A4%E3%83%99%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E4%BC%9D%E6%92%AD.php)

追記2：
質問のコードを実行エラーにならないよう修正して確認しました。

```
var layer = document.createElement("div");
layer.className = "layer";

window.onload = function() {
    document.body.onclick = function(event){console.log(event)};
    layer.onclick = function(event){console.log(event)};
}
```

結論としては「`click`イベントは発生していない」です。
`blur`イベントが起きたときに`click`イベントは無視されている･･･のではなくマスクされた要素の影響で`mouseup`イベントが来ないため`onclick`にならないんですね(ohgaさんの回答参照)。

Comment: document.body.onclick = function(event){console.log(event)};
はデバッグ用でtoElementがdiv.layerやdiv#tabにならないでbodyになるのはどういう意味なのかを知りたかったのです

Comment: 最終的にバブリングされてbodyのclickが発生するのは分かっているのですがクリックの発生元は何になるのだろうと思いまして。
個人的にはtabをclickする直前にlayerが挿入されることによりtabがクリック出来ないのかとも思ったのですがlayerがクリックされている訳でもなさそうなので。

Comment: 少なくとも`Firefox`では修正コードで`layer`がクリックされていますが･･･`tab`がクリックできないのは`z-index`の値が`layer`の方が大きく(明示的に指定しているわけではないが)、マスクされてしまっているからではないですか？

Comment: あぁすみません質問をよく読んでいませんでした･･･`focus`時に`tab`クリックですか。質問のコードではそもそも`document.body`が`null`となっており、実行エラーになっています。